# How to set Json data to chart.js bar

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

How to set json data to labels for Chart.js?

I have tried setting the array, customer formatted the string but for some reason its not working. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
var temp = "a,b,c,d";
var reportdata = [];
var labels = [];
while (i < temp.split(",")) {
                        labels.push(temp[i].toString());
                        i += 1;
                    }

var data = {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "",
                                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data: reportdata
                            }
                        ]
                    };
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to start with, 'split' creates an array, so you don't have to push the results of 'split' into a new array, just:

```
var temp = "a,b,c,d";
var labels = temp.split(",");
```

now labels[1] = b, etc.

Comment: Awesome!! That's what I was looking for. Thank you :)